# Generic function in jquery whit sweet alert 2 and replace confirm

Tags: sweetalert

I need create a generic function similar the confirm function in jquery using sweet alert 2.

```
var eval = ConfirmModalDelete("mensaje text");
        alert(eval);
```

The problem is when call the function "ConfirmModalDelete" jquery not wait for result of "swal".

```
function ConfirmModalDelete(mensaje) {

var retorno = false;

swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: mensaje,
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function (result) {
    if (result.value) {

        retorno = true;
    }
});


return retorno;
}
```

And the result is always "false".

Help please.

-------------------------------------Edit 09-07-2018------------------------
Eureka!
The solution is it:

```
 var fun = function()
 {
   alert("hello");
 }

 MensajeConfirm(fun);
```

Then:

```
function MensajeConfirm(func)
{
    swal({
        title: "title",
        text: "message",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        focusCancel: true
    }).then(function (eval) {

        if (eval.value) {
            //case press confirm
            func();
            //
        }
        if (eval.dismiss) {
            ///eval case esc|cancel
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a callback function and pass it in your function.

```
function handleOkClick(){
// do your stuff
}

function ConfirmModalDelete(mensaje, handleOkClick) {

swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: mensaje,
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function (result) {
    if (result.value) {

        handleOkClick();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use '.done' function:-

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'mensaje',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  } ).then(function (hello) {
    alert('dfasdfsd');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.12.10/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I'm just here to help you.

Comment: I have also tried it works some time and some time not workd

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest version of [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/). Your code example works fine:

```js
console.log(swal.version)
swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7"></script>
```

PS. notice that SweetAlert2 is a little bit different from SweetAlert, check the simple migration guide: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2

Comment: the problem is not sweetalert2, the problem is swal not wait for result. for example try put console.log replace for "return false"
function ResultofSwal(){
swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function (result) {
   return true;
});}


if call the function var e = ResultofSwal();
e is equals to undefined.